# Outlook to Gmail horizontal gaps

Tags: outlook, html-email

After a couple days of trying to figure this out via my own research, I've officially given up and have come to you experts for help.

I have a client who is requesting the following image be used for their email signature with phone number, email and website clickable, so I've resorted to slicing it up and going that route because image mapping isn't working when being sent from his Mac, although it works on his Mac when I send it via Gmail.

They are using Outlook on a Mac for their business. I'm testing this on Outlook via PC and on other clients via EmailOnAcid before delivering the end-product and having the following problems:

Outlook sent to Outlook

[image: image description]

Outlook to Gmail

[image: image description]

Outlook to Outlook w/ Line-Height: 0

[image: image description]

Outlook to Gmail w/ Line-Height: 0

[image: image description]
So essentially, everything initially looks great when sent from Outlook to Outlook, but those annoying horizontal gaps occur in Outlook to Gmail.

When I do the line-height trick, Outlook to Outlook now collapses upon itself while Gmail is now looking good.

I've tried all the tricks here - https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_fixes_for_the_image_spacing_in_html_emails - and elsewhere to no avail.

FYI The code might not be very consistent anymore because I've tried a bunch of different things, but it should give you an idea. Also, the resulting image is a bit over twice the size as what I need due to making things high-resolution in the end.

Any help would be super-appreciated... Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="980">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_01.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td height="49px"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_02.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td height="49px"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_03.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_04.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_05.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_06.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_07.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_08.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_09.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_10.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_11.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using Outlook to send the email?

Comment: Yes, as that is what the client will be installing the signature on and sending from. I know Outlook has its issues, but I feel like I'm so close to dialing this thing in.

Comment: Firstly drop the heights on td's, they have different results on email clients. Also is this what you did? _Preview the HTML and copy paste it in the signature. Enable signatures on outlook, compose email and send._ If not i would suggest you do this. Attaching a HTML to an email to send is not the best of tests.

Comment: No dice re: the td heights. They shouldn't have been there in the first place as they were a remnant of me trying to specify the size of every image, which didn't work either... I installed the signature by copying the raw code and ctrl-clicking the signature button in Outlook and pasting it in that file, as it's my understanding that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"` on every TD element and table. That will be your first step.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="980">
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_01.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td height="49px" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_02.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td height="49px" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_03.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_04.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_05.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_06.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_07.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_08.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_09.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_10.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td style="border-collapse: collapse !important;"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_11.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No dice... Looks the same as the original Outlook to Gmail example above. Thanks for the suggestion though... Hadn't tried that one yet!

Comment: Quick question - why wouldn't you just make it 1 image?

Comment: You mean to add image mapping/hotspots for the links? I did, and it works great on my end via Gmail, but doesn't work on client's end from Outlook on Mac... Hotspots are stripped out upon delivery.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some luck with this template in Outlook before. Frankly, I am not sure why. What I do to make it work is to open this in Word, copy and paste into Outlook. Dunno, Give it a try?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Email Signature</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #000;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 75%;
 line-height: 5px;
 top: auto;
}

/* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { /* Due to variations between browsers, it's best practices to zero padding and margin on lists. For consistency, you can either specify the amounts you want here, or on the list items (LI, DT, DD) they contain. Remember that what you do here will cascade to the .nav list unless you write a more specific selector. */
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
 margin-top: 0;  /* removing the top margin gets around an issue where margins can escape from their containing div. The remaining bottom margin will hold it away from any elements that follow. */
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px; /* adding the padding to the sides of the elements within the divs, instead of the divs themselves, gets rid of any box model math. A nested div with side padding can also be used as an alternate method. */
}
a img {
 border: none;
}
/* ~~ Styling for your site's links must remain in this order - including the group of selectors that create the hover effect. ~~ */
a:link {
 color: #42413C;
 text-decoration: underline; /* unless you style your links to look extremely unique, it's best to provide underlines for quick visual identification */
}
a:visited {
 color: #6E6C64;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { /* this group of selectors will give a keyboard navigator the same hover experience as the person using a mouse. */
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* ~~ this fixed width container surrounds all other elements ~~ */
.container {
 background-color: #FFF;
 margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
}

/* ~~ This is the layout information. ~~ 

1) Padding is only placed on the top and/or bottom of the div. The elements within this div have padding on their sides. This saves you from any "box model math". Keep in mind, if you add any side padding or border to the div itself, it will be added to the width you define to create the *total* width. You may also choose to remove the padding on the element in the div and place a second div within it with no width and the padding necessary for your design.

*/
.content {
 padding: 0px 0;
}

/* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
 float: right;
 margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element following the last floated div (within the #container) if the overflow:hidden on the .container is removed */
 clear:both;
 height:0;
 font-size: 1px;
 line-height: 0px;
}
.container .content div center a {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <blockquote>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="980">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_01.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td height="49px"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_02.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td height="49px"><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_03.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_04.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_05.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_06.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_07.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_08.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_09.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_10.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>

<td><img alt="Example Image" border="0" src="https://makalla.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Rebuilt-Signature-v4_11.jpg" style="display: block;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

   </blockquote>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and taking the time to put it together, but it's still the same result in Gmail as all of the other attempts... Isn't this Outlook thing frustrating?

Comment: Outlook is the worst email program ever made. And it will be the bane of your existence. I'd suggest just using a single image.

Comment: Agreed. That's what I ended up doing.